# Call to undefined function Mpdf\\Mpdf()

Tags: laravel-5, mpdf

I am trying to  download a pdf from blade view usign mPDF with laravel, but when I run the code, I get

> "message": "Call to undefined function Mpdf\Mpdf()",
>        "exception": "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError",

Does anyone know how to solve this.

I already have mpdf required in my composer

```php
"mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0", ...
```

EDIT:

```php
public function show(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $post);

    if ($request->input('view') === 'pdf') {

        $mpdf = \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        $html = '<h1>$post->title</h1>';

        $mpdf->writeHTML($html);

        $mpdf->Output('post.pdf', 'D');
    }

    return response($post);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are using `Mpdf\\Mpdf()` to your question.

Comment: I've already added  the code

Comment: You are missing the `new` keyword to instantiate a new instance of Mpdf. change `$mpdf = \Mpdf\Mpdf();` to `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();`. [Here](https://mpdf.github.io/getting-started/creating-your-first-file.html) is an example from the docs

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of \Mpdf\Mpdf() using the **new** keyword. Try if that works for you.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mpdf 8 version,
     $mpdf = new mpdf();

```
                $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($this->headernew(),'1', true);

               // $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($this->footer());

                $mpdf->AddPage('p','','','','',10,10,37,20,10,10);

                $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

                $mpdf->Output();
```